# Conflict between Google Analytics Embed API and Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-analytics-api

I am trying to combine use of a DataChart by means of the javascript Google Analytics Embed API and a HeatMap of the javascript Google Maps API in the same webpage. If I remove the reference to the maps api javascript, the DataChart works well. When I include the reference, the DataChart does not work and I receive: 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function'.

It appears the two javascript libraries are in conflict.

To be more clear, adding the maps api reference causes the problem with generating a DataChart:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=...&sensor=false&libraries=visualization"></script>
```

while removing the reference results in the DataChart rendering correctly.

Is anyone aware of such a conflict between the Google Analytics Embed API and the Google Maps API?

Comment: Can you please provide the code of how you are defining the union of both the APIs?